# After passing variable to async method, how will setting variable to new instance in main thread affect async method?

Tags: c#, multithreading

For instance:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    // Do stuff with o
    SomeAsyncMethod(o);
    o = new MyObject(); // Will this affect what was passed to SomeAsyncMethod?
}
```

Anything I do to 'o' will be obviously be apparent in both the main and the new thread.  However, if I set o equal to a new instance in the main thread it shouldn't change the fact the the variable in SomeAsyncMethod() is still pointing to the original instance of the object right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will have no effect on other o.
however

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    // Do stuff with o
    SomeAsyncMethod(o);
    o.Id = 2222; // will change objects Id property, which will 
                 // be reflected in another thread
}
```

the reason is in your code you are changing value (reference) of local variable o, not the object itself

Comment: Exactly what I thought.  Thanks!